# Add cofirmation message when ever user clicks on close button in WPF with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In WPF with MVVM,how to add a confirmation message when a user clicks on close button. Everytime,it just closes the window without any confirmation message whereas the same thing is happening in windows form.

In APP.XAML.CS

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Sure you wanna close?", "..", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
                e.ApplicationExitCode = 110;
            base.OnExit(e);
        }
    }
```

When i click on Close button it doesnt ask for confirmation just closes the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {            

        base.OnStartup(e);
        base.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;

        //update user settings (if first run after software upgrade)

        }

        // Initialise the application directory//

        // Set up the main window and its view model
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        mainWindow.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
        mainWindow.Show();

    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {



        e.ApplicationExitCode = 110;
        Dispose();
        base.OnExit(e);
```

}

Comment: Don't forget to call `base.OnClosing(e)`

Comment: HI in my APP.XAML.CS.  public partial class App : Application, IDisposable .Therefore i m getting error like 'System.Windows.Application' does not contain a definition for 'OnClosing'  while ovverriding OnClosing.so this wont be feasible

Answer (score 0):

You could use a behavior.

First of all, you have to add a reference to Interactivity in your project.

Go to References-addReference-assemblies-System.Windows.Interactivity.

Now, you create the behavior.

```
public class CloseWindowBehavior : Behavior<Window>
{

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.Closing += AssociatedObject_Closing;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Sure you wanna close?", "..", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

When you click on the close button, the event assigned will be fired, showing the message box.

Now, you have to declare this created behavior in your xaml file.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:CloseWindowBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Since you are using the pattern MVVM, behavior is a good choice since you don't need to write a single line in the code behind.